# SQL: Cant join Summed Metrics from various tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

EDIT: Rewriting for Clarity and example for simplicity

I have 3 levels of sales metrics (think of a sales funnel) with similar data points. These metrics are all housed on different tables and I have 4 common metrics which they can be joined together. I want to create a final table with my 4 common metrics of date, campaign, marketing_source, and country but each set of metrics will not join correctly with each other table. For example my date for campaignmember will be different for the date when the opportunity is created. To get around this I did a UNION and made a table which did a distinct union for all of the 4 metrics from my tables. This is used as the lookup table.

```
--Create the first table for inquiries (leads)
create table1 as (
select
id,
cast(createddate as date) as date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign
from campaignmembers
where createddate >= '1/1/2016');

--Create table2 for MQLs (Marketing Qualified Leads)
create table2 as (
select 
id,
cast(createddate as date) as date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign
from salesforcetasks
where createddate >= '1/1/2016'
and recordtype = 'Marketing');

--Create table3 for Opportunities
create table3 as (
select 
id,
cast(createddate as date) as date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign,
Case
WHEN stage = 'Closed Lost' then 0
ELSE amount
END as Pipeline
from Opportunities
where createddate >= '1/1/2016'
and marketing_source is not null);

--Use a union to ensure we can join all metrics
create table4 as (
select
distinct
date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign
from table1
UNION 
select
distinct
date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign
from table2
UNION 
select
distinct
date,
country,
marketing_source,
campaign
from table3)

--STEP 5 Pull it all together
Create table5 as (
select 
a.date,
a.country,
a.marketing_source,
a.campaign
count(b.id) as inquiries,
count(c.id) as mqls,
count(d.id) as opportunities,
sum(d.pipeline) as pipeline
from table4 a 
left join table1 b on a.date = b.date and a.country = b.country and a.marketing_source = b.marketing_source and a.campaign = b.campaign
left join table2 c on a.date = c.date and a.country = c.country and a.marketing_source = c.marketing_source and a.campaign = c.campaign
left join table3 d on a.date = d.date and a.country = d.country and a.marketing_source = d.marketing_source and a.campaign = d.campaign
group by 1,2,3,4
);
```

Ideally the number I get when I count(id) from table1 should be the same result as when I sum(inquiries) from table5. Unfortunately these metrics are just not adding up or accurate.

Comment: Just simplified the questions. Also I tried doing "count(ID) as Metric" on all tables1-3 and then on table5 doing sum(Metric) and the numbers changed from the previous query but they are still not accurate. No idea why they would change.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you're seeing. Can you provide example data (can be made up) that illustrates the divergence between the `count` in `table1` and the `sum` in `table4`? The only possible source of error I can imagine is when any of the columns would be allowed to take a `NULL` value. That would cause the join to fail and metrics to be missing. In that case you should see lower numbers in `table4` than are present in `table1`.